# База данных камер наблюдения CCTV

Tags: python, django, база-данных, искусственный-интеллект, видеонаблюдение

Для практики с Django, хочу создать карту с Google Maps API на которой можно выбрать фильтр камер наблюдений на улице, и чтобы появились иконки по всей открытой области, с координатами, где находятся камеры.

Существует ли такая база данных камер наружного наблюдения?

- Чтобы имелись геоданные камер
- Тип камер, например: со считыванием номеров, фоторадар или уличная камера

На данный момент карта имеет только один фильтр отображения трафика

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а в нашей деревне уже есть https://camera.lipetsk.ru/

Comment: @Интик А эти иконки камер автоматически присутсвуют в яндекс картах? Или это уже код?